# O que é timing-attack e onde ele se aplica?

Tags: segurança

Recebi uma resposta um tanto quanto interessante nesta pergunta:

[Qual a possibilidade de encontrar uma determinada string de 192 caracteres em 10 minutos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207371/qual-a-possibilidade-de-encontrar-uma-determinada-string-de-192-caracteres-em-10/207557#207557)

Porém não compreendi o que se trata o **timing-attack**.

Como parece ser algo mais complexo e que foge do contexto original daquela pergunta, resolvi abrir outra.

Sei que é uma vulnerabilidade, mas mais especificamente do que?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ele é um problema que afeta qualquer coisa que não possui tempo constante, acredito que melhor explicar com exemplos, *talvez alguém responda a parte mais teórica*.

Suponha este tipo de código, em PHP:

```
function tem_simbolo_na_senha($texto)
{

    $texto = str_split($texto);

    foreach ($texto as $letra) {

        if ($letra == "#" || $letra == "@" || $letra == "%" || $letra == "&") {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Alguém criou porque o sistema exige que o usuário digite um simbolo na senha, isso é um `#`, `@`, `%` ou um `&`, então precisa verificar se a senha tem um caractere deste tipo. Se você viu o erro neste códio então já sabe o que o timming-attack é, em sua base.

O problema do código acima é que o `return` é emitido antes ou depois dependendo do texto. Isso é quanto antes houver um simbolo mais rápido será retornado `true`, portanto considere essas duas senhas:

```
$texto = 'yuqkdp69yHryACb778mvZsbFegIBU#';
                                       ^
$texto = 'yuqk#p69yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBUh';
               ^
```

Se mensuramos a média de tempo para que cada uma verificação seja feita teríamos:

```
yuqk#p69yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBUh demorou 1.6998052597046E-6
yuqkdp69yHryACb778mvZsbFegIBU# demorou 5.058741569519E-6
```

[Veja isto, aqui.](https://3v4l.org/4AcU6)

*Em todos os testes o `yuqkdp69yHryACb778mvZsbFegIBU#` é mais lento.*

---

Isso não é apenas para "o que você cria", os recursos padrões da linguagem também são vulneráveis, imagine isto:

```
if($usuario === 'inkeliz'){
}
```

Agora observe a implementação do PHP para o `===`:

```
ZEND_API int ZEND_FASTCALL zend_is_identical(zval *op1, zval *op2) /* {{{ */
{
    if (Z_TYPE_P(op1) != Z_TYPE_P(op2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    switch (Z_TYPE_P(op1)) {
    //...
        case IS_STRING:
            return (Z_STR_P(op1) == Z_STR_P(op2) ||
                (Z_STRLEN_P(op1) == Z_STRLEN_P(op2) &&
                 memcmp(Z_STRVAL_P(op1), Z_STRVAL_P(op2), Z_STRLEN_P(op1)) == 0));
    //...
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

[Código fonte](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a08723d3d313445191470c19e12235a56165600a/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2110-L2138)

Não possuo muito conhecimento em C. Mas, até onde sei se ambos forem apontados para mesmo endereço da memoria `Z_STR_P(op1) == Z_STR_P(op2)` ele retornará `true`, *de imediato*. Se não, eles devem ter o mesmo tamanho `Z_STRLEN_P(op1) == Z_STRLEN_P(op2)` e então vai usar o [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/).

Se formos mais em baixo vamos ver que o `memcmp` é:

```
int
memcmp(s1, s2, n)
    CONST VOID *s1;         /* First string. */
    CONST VOID *s2;         /* Second string. */
    size_t      n;                      /* Length to compare. */
{
    unsigned char u1, u2;

    for ( ; n-- ; s1++, s2++) {
    u1 = * (unsigned char *) s1;
    u2 = * (unsigned char *) s2;
    if ( u1 != u2) {
        return (u1-u2);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Segundo este código fonte.](https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-3.1/tcl/compat/memcmp.c)

Observe a semelhança deste código para o primeiro exemplo, do PHP, é praticamente idêntico! Ele dará um return se o `u1 != u2`, ou seja no primeiro bit diferente ele irá emitir *algo diferente de 0*.

Portanto:

```
$usuario === 'inkeliz'
```

Considerando isto:

```
ixxxxxx
```

Irá demorar mais do que isto:

```
axxxxxx
```

Portanto de pouco em pouco nós conseguimos:

```
iaxxxxx
ibxxxxx
...
inxxxxx
inaxxxx
...
inkxxxx
```

O `inkelia` será *muito* mais demorado do que o `axxxxxx`, o `memcmp` vai abandonar o barco somente na última letra enquanto no segundo caso ele entrega na primeira diferença, *na primeira letra*.

---

Então como podemos fazer algo que não seja vulnerável? Mantendo o tempo igual, ou o mais próximo disso, um tempo que não tenha relação com o input de fato.

No primeiro exemplo poderiamos fazer:

```
function tem_simbolo_na_senha($texto)
{

    $return = 0;

    $tamanho = mb_strlen($texto, '8bit');

    for($i = 0; $i < $tamanho; $i++){

        $return |= (int)($texto[$i] === "#" xor $texto[$i] === "@" xor $texto[$i] === "%" xor $texto[$i] === "&");

    }

    return $return !== 0;

}
```

Isso iria fazer com que:

```
1 - yuqkdp69yHryACb778mvZsbFegIBU# demorou 6.3819885253906E-6
1 - yuqk#p69yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBUh demorou 6.4213275909424E-6
1 - yuqksp69yHryACb778m#Zs#Fi#IBUh demorou 6.2981128692627E-6
0 - yuqksp69yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBUh demorou 6.1065435409546E-6
1 - yuqksp69yHryACb778mvZsb%igIBUh demorou 5.9833765029907E-6
1 - yuqksp69yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBU& demorou 6.1017274856567E-6
1 - yuqksp@9yHryACb778mvZsbFigIBUh demorou 6.4485788345337E-6
```

[Veja isto](https://3v4l.org/RDYUQ)

Ou seja, o tempo de processamento independe do input, independe de onde está o caractere especial. É lógico os tempos médio em alguns casos podem ser diferentes, mas não está relacionado ao input, *se ainda sim for influenciado será uma influencia muito menor*.

Porque isso é melhor?

1. O `$return` guarda o retorno, mas não emite ele de imediato, assim percorrendo todo o resto, independente de se encontrar outro ou não.
2. O `xor` exige que todas condições do `if` sejam executadas, se continuasse com o `||` ele irá encerrar assim que a primeira condição retornasse `true`.

---

Já o caso da comparação é diferentes, a maior parte das linguagens de programação possuem uma biblioteca de criptografia, elas *sempre* incluem uma função segura de comparação, o PHP possui o `hash_equals`, o Golang tem o `ConstantTimeCompare`, o Phyton tem o `hmac.compare_digest`...

Mas em geral fazemos:

```
while(tamanho_string){

    retorno |= 'A' ^ 'B'

    return retorno

}
```

No caso do PHP seria:

```
function comparacao_segura($input, $segredo){

    $return = 0;

    $tamanhoSegredo = mb_strlen($segredo, '8bit');
    $tamanhoInput = mb_strlen($input, '8bit');

    if($tamanhoSegredo !== $tamanhoInput){
        return false;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $tamanhoSegredo; $i++) {      
        $return |= (unpack('C', $input[$i])[1] ^ unpack('C', $segredo[$i])[1]);
    }

    return $return === 0; 

}
```

Isso é seguro porque?

1. Simples, ele vai executar por toda string, não dando um `return` quando um bit é diferente.
2. O `$return` sempre será atualizado, independente se ele é ou não verdadeiro, logo não cria um *Branching Timing Attacks* e o tempo será igual.

Se nunca viu operações bitwise antes, então essa seria o funcionamento por trás:

Dado `comparacao_segura("A...", "B...")`, ele vai:

```
A = 65
B = 66
```

Depois o que faz é um xor:

```
65 ^ 66
```

Que é na verdade:

```
  0100 0010
  0100 0001
= 0000 0011
```

Então ele faz um `ou` (`|`) com o valor que estava previamente armazenado, no caso:

```
 0000 0000
 0000 0011
= 0000 0011
```

Que no final será diferente de `0`.

Se forem iguais, o `^` dará `00000000` em todas as comparações, logo o `or` de `00000000` com `00000000` será `0000000` e portanto será === 0.

Qual é a falha?

Ele expõe o tamanho do segredo, isso em geral não é visto como um problema, inclusive a implementação do Phyton *tem* este problema, dito na documentação.

Existe como "corrigir" isto?

Não exatamente, *devido ao `strlen`*, mas é possível chegar próximo:

```
function comparacao_mais_segura($input, $segredo){

    $return = 0;

    $tamanhoInput = mb_strlen($input, '8bit');
    $tamanhoSegredo = mb_strlen($segredo, '8bit');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $tamanhoInput; $i++) {        
        $return |= (unpack('C', $input[$i])[1] ^ unpack('C', $segredo[$i % $tamanhoSegredo])[1]);
    }

    return $return === 0; 

}
```

Isso é um pouco matemático, logo a alteração é:

```
$i % $tamanhoSegredo
```

Isso quer dizer que em `comparacao_mais_segura('ABCDEF', 'AB')`, na primeira vez será 0 % 2 = 0, depois, 1 % 2 = 1, depois 2 % 2 = 0, depois 3 % 2 = 1....

Porém em geral o Length timing attack, como é chamado, não é considerado um problema tão grave, uma vez que conhecer o tamanho não faz saber o seu conteúdo.

---

Uma outra questão é não fazer isto, que é considerado vulnerável por "*Branching Timing Attack*":

```
if(algo){
    funcao()
}else{
    outra_coisa()
}
```

Suponha que o `encontrou_cadastro` procura pelo e-mail do usuário no banco de dados (ex. "`SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Email = ?`").

```
if(encontrou_cadastro($_POST['email'])){

    compara_senha($_POST['senha'])

}
```

Mesmo que o tempo da query seja rápida o suficiente,que por si já não é, ainda existe um problema.

Isso é um tanto lógico, a função `compara_senha()` somente será chamada se for encontrado o usuário, portanto é possível que alguém, baseado no tempo, consiga descobrir se um e-mail está cadastrado ou não.

Neste caso se o `xxx@yyy.zzz` estiver cadastrado ele irá comparar a senha, se não irá executar nada. Logo, se a página "demorar" é porque este e-mail existe, se não ele não existe, mesmo que claramente não diga isto ao usuário ele é capaz de saber.

Isso depende do contexto para ser considerado ou não um problema. Se o seu website já informa "e-mail já cadastrado" ao tentar se cadastrar, então o e-mail não é uma informação secreta, logo usar o código acima não é um problema de segurança, o e-mail não é secreto.

Se isto for um problema, então faça algo como:

```
if(encontrou_cadastro($_POST['email'])){
    compara_senha($_POST['senha'], senha_do_banco())
}else{
    compara_senha($_POST['senha'], 'hahs-de-uma-senha-idiota')
}
```

Assim ambos os casos vão usar o `compara_senha`, anulando suas diferentes, supondo que eles utilizem comparações seguras. :D

---

Existem soluções genéricas, que é de fazer um `sleep`. Isso é usado não conseguimos manter uma função em tempo constante então fazemos isso "na força bruta". Determinamos que a função deve sempre demorar 200ms, assim independente do que ocorra demorará 200ms. O problema disso é:

1. Definir um tempo fixo longo demais expõe um possível DoS.
2. Definir um tempo fixo curto demais acaba com a "proteção".
3. Isto apenas afeta remotamente, mas não localmente, logo um "local timing attack" ainda é totalmente possível, afinal a função em si não é constant-time.

---

Quando se fala em "local timing attack" a coisa piora, isso porque existe muito mais informações, é possível saber onde o dado está armazenado (ex. na RAM, no cache L1, L2, L3) somente baseado no tempo, cada um possui velocidades diferentes, logo isto é físico e não de software. Neste caso existem mais ataques, que inclusive são o "maior problema" para criptografia, mas desse assunto não entendo tanto. :(

Comment: Muito boa a explicação, parabéns.

Answer (score 6):

Existe um ditado popular:

> Mente vazia, oficina do diabo.

Que poderia ser modificado para se encaixar perfeitamente nesta pergunta:

> Tempo Ocioso, Oficina do Tinhoso(ou do Hacker, ou do mal elemento em questão)

Mas deixa de gracinha =) e vamos lá:

Resumidamente, com tradução livre, adaptado para questão, da [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)<sup>en</sup>:

> Na criptografia, *Timing Attack* é um ataque *Side Channel* no qual o invasor tenta comprometer um sistema de criptografia, analisando o tempo necessário para executar algoritmos criptográficos. Cada operação lógica em um computador leva tempo para executar, e o tempo pode se diferenciar com base na entrada.
>
> Sendo assim, informações podem vazar de um sistema através da medição do tempo que leva para responder as determinadas consultas(*query*). O quanto essas informações podem ajudar um atacante depende de muitas variáveis: design do sistema de criptografia, a CPU executando o sistema, os algoritmos utilizados, detalhes de implementação variados, contramedidas de ataque de tempo, a precisão das medições de tempo, etc...

## O que é o *Timing Attack*?

*Timing Attack*, como o nome diz, é um tipo de ataque à sistemas baseado no tempo. Basicamente o ataque consiste em tentar descobrir informações relevantes de um sistema analisando o tempo que o sistema leva para realizar determinadas operações.

Como o computador funciona com um processador baseado em ciclos, o tempo gasto para realizar o mesmo conjunto de operações mais de uma vez é praticamente idêntico. Então se a pessoa consegue interagir com o sistema passando um dado de entrada diferente, ele consegue analisar o tempo que levou para processar aquela informação.

## Mais especificamente do que?

Normalmente, este tipo de ataque está associado ao roubo de dados(como exemplo, descoberta de senhas). Quando, por exemplo, uma pessoa tenta explorar o formulário de "login" do sistema passando senhas diferentes e analisando o tempo que o sistema levou para dizer que a senha é inválida.

A ideia central deste ataque é explorar um comportamento dos sistemas durante a comparação de strings. Normalmente as linguagens de programação oferecem um mecanismo para comparação de strings que percorre caractere por caractere, comparando-os e retornando false assim que encontra uma diferença. Ou seja, se o primeiro caractere de duas strings já forem diferentes, a operação levará pouquíssimo tempo para descobrir que as strings são diferentes. Porém, se as duas strings forem grandes e os 100 primeiros caracteres forem iguais, mas o 101º for diferente, então a operação levará mais tempo, pois precisará percorrer 100 caracteres até perceber a diferença.

## Como se prevenir deste ataque?

Uma solução é fazer com que determinada operação sensível ao tempo seja realizada em um tempo que não ajude ninguém a descobrir informações, por exemplo, realizando a operação em um tempo constante ou então realizando em um tempo totalmente aleatório. E foi feita, no **PHP 5.6**, foi criada a função *[hash_equals](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/timing_attack)* da extensão *[hash](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.hash.php)*. Ela faz exatamente isso que é preciso, ou seja, uma comparação segura quanto ao tempo para comparar *hashes* de senhas.

## Onde ele se aplica?

Por ser uma brecha de segurança, ele se aplica a **quase** <sub>Não tenho certeza</sub> todos os sistemas. Por exemplo, toda aplicação que precise fazer comparações de strings(algo que quase todos sistemas fazem, uma vez que em um sistema de login, há a necessidade de se comparar um *hash*) estão vulneráveis a não ser que já tenha tomado as devidas providências de segurança.

## Veja mais perguntas e definições relacionadas:

- [Definition of *Timing Attack*](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/timing-attack)
- *Information Security* - *[Does bcrypt compare the hashes in “length-constant” time?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/does-bcrypt-compare-the-hashes-in-length-constant-time/46215#46215)*
- *Information Security* - *[Simple string comparisons not secure against timing attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83660/simple-string-comparisons-not-secure-against-timing-attacks)*
- [Prevenção do *Timing Attack* em *PHP*](https://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/prevencao-de-timing-attack-no-php.html?m=0)
- Information Security - *[Are timing attacks for PHP used in practice?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154589/are-timing-attacks-for-php-used-in-practice)*
- StackOverFlow - *[Preventing Timing Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030017/preventing-timing-attacks)*
- Cryptography - *[Practical Uses for Timing Attacks on Hash Comparisons (e.g. MD5)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25607/practical-uses-for-timing-attacks-on-hash-comparisons-e-g-md5)*

## Fonte

- [Prevenção de *Timing Attack* no *PHP*](https://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/prevencao-de-timing-attack-no-php.html?m=0)