# Como realizar comparação segura de 2 Hashes em Node.js?

Tags: node.js, string, segurança

Estou estudando sobre *timing attack* e encontrei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207650/o-que-%C3%A9-timing-attack-e-onde-ele-se-aplica/207747#207747) relacionada ao tema, e identifiquei o problema que comparação de string hash pode provocar nesse tipo de ataque.

O problema é que temos microsserviços que são APIs fechadas para uso por outras APIs internas, como se fosse um *Back-end for Back-end* e para que essas APIs internas sejam consumidas, algumas restrições são feitas. Uma delas é a verificação de uma chave de API que fica em um header `x-api-key`, onde a verificação é feita por um *middleware* com um código semelhante a esse:

```
function checkApiKey(req, res, next) {
  const { 'x-api-key': apiKey } = req.headers

  if(apiKey !== process.env.API_KEY) {
    throw new InvalidApiKey();
  }
  ...

  return next()
}
```

O código acima não é muito seguro com essa comparação `!==`. Eu esperava o uso de alguma biblioteca para realizar essa comparação, mas pelo visto o desenvolvedor que fez o código não conhece sobre o problema de TA. Na verdade, os sistemas usam algumas soluções duvidosas e bem questionáveis.

As chaves de APIs podem ser no formato semelhante à essa:

> 89JhP8rekXxwJMEr9khQuVKAVrdKaOfp2jCc5hV54BAbAHoeujAGvjGxTZkdBSnMXpHzijl8SC8WNLgoeWKATM3STe5Se9IM22NmerIPlcp71zwfX7O112OkY0K2T3dz

Dito isto, sabendo que eu preciso de uma solução que resulte em tempo constante de operação, como eu resolveria essa comparação de forma segura em Node.js?

Uma das [respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207747/95771) menciona a função `hash_compare` para comparação de hashes. Qual seria a equivalente em Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A biblioteca nativa `crypto`

Com `crypto`, podemos realizar comparações seguras de hashes. Ela possui uma função chamada `timingSafeEqual` (acho que o nome já explica tudo).

Vamos com um exemplo:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

// criamos 2 hashes aleatorios
const hash1 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('hash1').digest();
const hash2 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('hash2').digest();

// aqui é feita a comparacao segura
const result = crypto.timingSafeEqual(hash1, hash2);

if (result) {
  console.log('As hashes são iguais');
} else {
  console.log('As hashes são diferentes');
}
```

Porém, por mais que essa solução resolva o problema, ela tem alguns detalhes importantes. `timingSafeEqual` recebe apenas **`Buffers` de mesmo tamanho** como parâmetros, ou seja, para o código mencionado na pergunta funcionar, `apiKey` e `process.env.API_KEY` precisam ser convertidos em Buffers.

Veja o código atualizado:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function checkApiKey(req, res, next) {
  const { 'x-api-key': apiKey } = req.headers;

  const apiKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(apiKey, 'utf8');
  const envApiKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(process.env.API_KEY, 'utf8');

  if (!crypto.timingSafeEqual(apiKeyBuffer, envApiKeyBuffer)) {
    throw new InvalidApiKey();
  }
  ...
  return next();
}
```

Nesta solução acima, considero que já foi feita uma validação prévia do tamanho das strings e que ambas sejam de tamanho igual, antes de converter para Buffers. Caso contrário, `timingSafeEqual` irá lançar um erro. Isso pode ser facilmente adicionando um `if` anterior que compara o tamanho das strings.

## Bibliotecas do NPM

Caso você uma solução mais simples, existem alguns pacotes do NPM para alcançar o mesmos objetivo. Elas já resolvem problemas como ter que garantir strings com possíveis tamanhos diferentes e conversões para Buffer.

#### [tsse](https://npmjs.com/package/tsse)

Isso difere de `crypto.timingSafeEqual` porque ele:

- suporta tanto strings quanto Buffers;
- suporta entradas de tamanhos diferentes.

---

```
const tsse = require('tsse');

const hash      = '0a4d55a8d778e5022fab701977c5d840bbc486d0';
const givenHash = '1265a5eb08997ced279d3854629cba68a378b528';

if (tsse(hash, givenHash)) {
  console.log('good hash');
} else {
  console.log('bad hash');
}
// => bad hash
```

#### [safe-compare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-compare)

Idem, mas sem updates já tem 4 anos.

```
var safeCompare = require('safe-compare');
 
safeCompare('hello world', 'hello world'); // -> true
 
safeCompare('hello', 'not hello'); // -> false
safeCompare('hello foo', 'hello bar'); // -> false
```